# How to detect motion on camera to move mouse

Tags: camera, motion-detection

We are doing experiment with our webcam. We want to move mouse pointer with camera by moving an easily identifieable object in front of camera. For example move an led in dark room in front of camera and it will detect the motion.

How do we do that? Program a software that capture each image, process it, find the position of light and set mouse accordingly?
Is there any ready made library (c#) for doing such thing.

Comment: This is a very advanced question. The technology is called "motion tracking", and things like this have already been done, even in Flash. Check this out: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ux6Ihiy6ZLA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For C#

[Touchless](http://www.officelabs.com/projects/touchless/) By microsoft
[Touchless on codeplex](http://touchless.codeplex.com)

[AForge.Net website](http://www.aforgenet.com/)
[AForge.Net Framework googel code](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/)

Answer (score 2):

u may want to use opencv for your project..

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/index.html

Comment: sry have no idea about c#... maybe somebody else here woul answer... :)